# Why is sort method behaving differently in Node and Chrome when they are both powered by v8 engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, chromium

simple sorting in ascending order;

in `node v10.15.3`

[image: node]

in chrome `Chromium 79.0.3945.88`:

[image: Chromium 79.0.3945.88]

Comment: you have no stable return value.

Comment: You should not let the `sort` callback return a boolean (which never can be -1). You should return a number, that is negative when `a < b`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what's the 'sort' method's difference between chrome environment and node environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56320307/whats-the-sort-methods-difference-between-chrome-environment-and-node-enviro)

Comment: That dupe target has an answer by a v8 developer, take a look.

Comment: @Klaycon yes. thanks a ton for that

Comment: Your "simple sorting" is [using a broken comparison function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785/1048572)